# Filtering JSON api response in apex

Tags: json, filters

I have a json response that is got from a customer search API. This response contains multiple customer which is got according to the search request criteria. I want to filter this response including only the customers which have '*aliasType = 2*'

So in the below given response, it shows details of two customers (can be many). I want a json which excludes the customers with *aliasType* not equal to *2*. There may be multiple *aliasType* under *custAliasRecords*, still if any one of the *custAliasRecords* contains aliasType=2, then the customer should be included in the result.
Please help me in getting this achieved in apex page. Is there any built in  class/method that facilitate this filtering in salesforce.

```
"Customers": [
{
  "crcId": "48100004158",
  "memberId": "PB00000000002572816",
  "enrollmentLocationId": "9114",
  "firstName": "Mile",
  "lastName": "Stey",
  "salutation": "Mrs",
  "birthDate": null,
  "genderCode": "F",
  "emailAddress": "asd@asd.com",
  "emailModificationDate": null,
  "mobilePhoneNumber": "+1234567890",
  "mobileModificationDate": null,
  "chainId": "1 ",
  "createdDate": null,
  "languageCode": "EN",
  "lastUpdateDate": null,
  "lastUpdateSource": " LOC",
  "customerAddress": [
    {
      "crcId": "48100004158",
      "addressType": "1",
      "addressLine1": "Dallas",
      "addressLine2": "",
      "city": "Texas",
      "state": "TX",
      "country": "US",
      "postalCode": "75201",
      "lastUpdateDate": null,
      "lastUpdateSource": "INTF249 File [FileId: 2887]"
    }
  ],
  "membership": {
    "memberId": "PB00000000002572816",
    "memberStatus": "1",
    "memberModificationDate": null,
    "accountId": null,
    "enrollmentDate": null,
    "referenceType": "0",
    "custAliasRecords": [
      {
        "memberId": "PB00000000002572816",
        "aliasType": "1",
        "aliasNumber": "3104172445011428",
        "aliasStatus": "0",
        "lastUpdateDate": null,
        "lastUpdateSource": "Web"
      },
      {
        "memberId": "PB00000000002572816",
        "aliasType": "2",
        "aliasNumber": "7221180000064683",
        "aliasStatus": "0",
        "lastUpdateDate": null,
        "lastUpdateSource": " LOC"
      }
    ],
    "dataRightsIndicator": "Y",
    "dataRightsDate": null,
    "enrollmentStatus": "P"
  }
},
{
  "crcId": "48200002849",
  "memberId": "PB00000000002572816",
  "enrollmentLocationId": "9114",
  "firstName": "Mile",
  "lastName": "Stey",
  "salutation": "Mrs",
  "birthDate": null,
  "genderCode": "F",
  "emailAddress": "asd@asd.com",
  "emailModificationDate": null,
  "mobilePhoneNumber": "+1234567890",
  "mobileModificationDate": null,
  "chainId": "2 ",
  "createdDate": null,
  "languageCode": "EN",
  "lastUpdateDate": null,
  "lastUpdateSource": " LOC",
  "customerAddress": [
    {
      "crcId": "48200002849",
      "addressType": "1",
      "addressLine1": "Dallas",
      "addressLine2": "",
      "city": "Texas",
      "state": "TX",
      "country": "US",
      "postalCode": "75201",
      "lastUpdateDate": null,
      "lastUpdateSource": "INTF249 File [FileId: 2887]"
    }
  ],
  "membership": {
    "memberId": "PB00000000002572816",
    "memberStatus": "1",
    "memberModificationDate": null,
    "accountId": null,
    "enrollmentDate": null,
    "referenceType": "0",
    "custAliasRecords": [
      {
        "memberId": "PB00000000002572816",
        "aliasType": "1",
        "aliasNumber": "3104172445011428",
        "aliasStatus": "0",
        "lastUpdateDate": null,
        "lastUpdateSource": "Web"
      },
      {
        "memberId": "PB00000000002572816",
        "aliasType": "1",
        "aliasNumber": "7221180000064683",
        "aliasStatus": "0",
        "lastUpdateDate": null,
        "lastUpdateSource": " LOC"
      }
    ],
    "dataRightsIndicator": "Y",
    "dataRightsDate": null,
    "enrollmentStatus": "P"
  },
  "customerAttributes": [
    {
      "crcId": "48200002849",
      "attributeId": "1100",
      "attributeCode": "9114",
      "lastUpdateDate": null,
      "lastUpdateSource": " LOC"
    },
    {
      "crcId": "48200002849",
      "attributeId": "1101",
      "attributeCode": "9114",
      "lastUpdateDate": null,
      "lastUpdateSource": " LOC"
    },
    {
      "crcId": "48200002849",
      "attributeId": "1102",
      "attributeCode": "1",
      "lastUpdateDate": null,
      "lastUpdateSource": " LOC"
    },
    {
      "crcId": "48200002849",
      "attributeId": "1103",
      "attributeCode": "91142018030911060010019",
      "lastUpdateDate": null,
      "lastUpdateSource": " LOC"
    },
    {
      "crcId": "48200002849",
      "attributeId": "1104",
      "attributeCode": "3/9/2018",
      "lastUpdateDate": null,
      "lastUpdateSource": " LOC"
    },
    {
      "crcId": "48200002849",
      "attributeId": "1106",
      "attributeCode": "58cce5b7d9658acc99c40a681fc882a5afd0e8eb04950e3a0c1e24534f9d6aa7",
      "lastUpdateDate": null,
      "lastUpdateSource": null
    },
    {
      "crcId": "48200002849",
      "attributeId": "1202",
      "attributeCode": "3/9/2018",
      "lastUpdateDate": null,
      "lastUpdateSource": " LOC"
    },
    {
      "crcId": "48200002849",
      "attributeId": "1213",
      "attributeCode": "48200002849",
      "lastUpdateDate": null,
      "lastUpdateSource": "INTF249 File [FileId: 2887]"
    }
  ]
}
```

],
  "IsSuccessful": true,
  "ErrorMessage": null
}

**EDIT 1:**

Finally I have managed to create the class structure and log all the customers. Now please help in the final step, which is the filtering part. I want only the customers to add who has aliasType = 2. Please the filtering function that i have written.

```
 public void Filter(String jsonString){
    List<CustomerSet.Customer> customers = new List<CustomerSet.Customer>();
    // Parse entire JSON response.
    JSONParser parser = JSON.createParser(jsonString);
    while (parser.nextToken() != null) 
    {
        // Start at the array of customers.
        if (parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.START_ARRAY) 
        {
            while (parser.nextToken() != null) 
            {
                //  find next Customer object.
                if (parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.START_OBJECT) 
                {
                    // Read entire Customer object
                    CustomerSet.Customer vs = (CustomerSet.Customer)parser.readValueAs(CustomerSet.Customer.class);
                    System.debug('Customer: ' + vs);
                    System.debug('Customer Class: ' + CustomerSet.Customer.class);

                    if( check if aliasType==2 ){

                        //customers.add(vs);

                    }
                    parser.skipChildren();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    System.debug('Filtered Customer: ' + customers);
}
```

Comment: You can deserialize the JSON into an Apex object or map and perform filtering in Apex. This topic gets discussed here a lot; if you search SFSE for "JSON deserialization" you'll find many resources.

Comment: @DavidReed Can you please share some reference link that will be appropriate for my scenario?

Comment: You need an Apex class to act as an object that will hold the JSON data in records that you can work with.  To create the Apex class from sample JSON, use the [JSON2Apex utility](https://json2apex.herokuapp.com/).

Comment: @DavidCheng Thanks. That's a quick way to create custom class. Now any quick way to map each customer into a list ? I have created a list of customers.       `List<Customer> customercLst= new List<Customer>();`

Comment: This is where a web search on JSON deserialize will give you a great learning experience.

Comment: Please see the edit 1

Comment: @saugandh k avoid, asking follow up question(s) as post Edits, instead, opena a new one, and specify what problem you are facing alongside any errors.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this type of problem, where we build a list of parent records and choose which ones to exclude based on attributes of their child records, is to do something like this for each parent. We set a Boolean variable to `true`, since including records is the default, and loop over the children. When we find a child that meets the criteria for *excluding* this parent record, we set the boolean to `false` and break out of the loop.

Then, we use the Boolean to decide whether or not to add the parent record to our `List`. If we never found a qualifying child record, it remains `true`.

```
Boolean shouldIncludeThisRecord = true;

// Iterate over the child records to see if one of them
// meets the criteria for excluding its parent.
for (ChildRecord c : thisRecord.children) {
    if (c.Dont_Include_Parent__c) {
        shouldIncludeThisRecord = false;
        break;
    }
}

// If we didn't find a record that would exclude the parent, 
// shouldIncludeThisRecord remains true.
if (shouldIncludeThisRecord) {
    listOfParentRecords.add(thisRecord);
}
```

In this situation, your parent record is `CustomerSet.Customer`, and your child records are the list `membership.custAliasRecords`, whatever type that happens to be. Your version of `c.Dont_Include_Parent__c` would be a check to see if `aliasType` is equal to `2`.

You would need to adapt the pseudo-code above to fit that situation.

Comment: How to access aliyasType value. I just tried with  `System.debug('custAliasRecords: ' + vs.Membership.custAliasRecords);` which logs the custAliasRecords value sets.

Comment: @saugandhk, I can't answer that because you haven't provided your data structures. However, this is really a question that you should be able to answer yourself based on how you are storing this data.